# Maintaining customized branches in Git (hiding files)

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to implement a use case described as "maintaining a fork with customizations to the upstream repo" in this page: https://gist.github.com/rvl/c3f156e117e22a25f242

In a nutshell, I want to push my code to 3 different locations - one *master* location, and two abridged versions. I will be making modifications only to *master* and then merging into the branches. I am trying to do this via 3 different branches with different remote URLs except I want to hide some files from branches 1 & 2:

master -> in-house repo

branch 1 -> remote #1 (exclude file A)

branch 2 -> remote #2 (exclude file B)

I've already set up the remotes. I know how to branch *master* and set its remote to something else. My concern is removing individual files *completely* from each branch's history. I've used *git filter-branch* previously but have some concerns:

1. Will I end up deleting file A from every single branch? Is it possible to delete file A from branch 1 only and file B from branch 2 only in a way that it's impossible to get it from history?
2. What will happen when I merge *master* into each branch? Will it pull files A and B? Is it possible to set up a .gitignore for each branch?

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Separate repos for files A and B?

Answer (score 0):

For your questions:

#### 1. You can use git filter-branch to rewrite only one branch. Such as remove fileA only in branch1, remove file B only in branch2.

Detail steps to achieve as below:

- Remove `fileA` in `branch1`:

  **First**, get the first commit on `branch1` by `git log branch1 --oneline`. It will listu the commits on branch1 as below:

  ```
  commitN message N
  …
  commit2  mesaage2
  commit1 message1
  ```

  The first commit for `branch1` in bottom and the latest commit for `branch1` is on the top. So you need to get the commit id for `commit1`.

  **Then**, remove `fileA` in `branch1` by

  ```
  git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch fileA' --prune-empty -f -- commit1..branch1
  ```

  Now `fileA` is removed completely in `branch1`.
- Remove `fileB` in `branch2` (use the same method):

  **First**, get the first commit (assume it’s `commitb1`) for `branch2` by `git log branch2 --oneline`.

  **Then**, remove fileB in branch2 by

  ```
  git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch fileB' --prune-empty -f -- commitb1..branch2
  ```

#### 2. You should add .gitignore in branch1 and branch2 separately

When you merge `master` into `branch1` and `branch2` separately, the `fileA` and `fileB` will be added separtely. So you should add `.gitignore` files for `branch1` and `branch2` separately before merging:

```
git checkout branch1
touch .gitignore
echo fileA >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'add .gitignore for branch1'
git checkout branch2
touch .gitignore
echo fileB >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'add .gitignore for branch2'
```

Now you can merge `master` into `branch1` and `branch2`, and `fileA` and `fileB` won’t be added in `branch1` and `branch2` separately.

Besides, it's unnecessary to manage `fileA` and `fileB` in separate repos. Below way can achieve the requirement better.